# How to keep UNUserNotificationCenter sound playing until user stops it

Tags: ios, unusernotificationcenter, swift4.2

There are a few articles that address this same problem, but (from what I've seen) they're all from 4 years ago and in Objective-C. I'm working with Swift 4.2.

I'm making a countdown timer app. While the app is in the background and a timer expires, I want the notification sound to keep playing until the user stops it by tapping on the notification.

So far, what I have only plays an alert sound once from the background/lockscreen.

Here is the method I am working with.

```
func notifications(title: String, message: String){

    center.delegate = self

    let restartAction = UNNotificationAction(identifier: "RESTART_ACTION", title: "Restart timer", options: UNNotificationActionOptions(rawValue: 0))

    let stopAction = UNNotificationAction(identifier: "STOP_ACTION", title: "Stop", options: UNNotificationActionOptions(rawValue: 0))

    let expiredCategory = UNNotificationCategory(identifier: "TIMER_EXPIRED", actions: [restartAction, stopAction], intentIdentifiers: [], options: UNNotificationCategoryOptions(rawValue: 0))

    // Register the notification categories.
    center.setNotificationCategories([expiredCategory])

    let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
    content.title = title
    content.body = message
    content.categoryIdentifier = "TIMER_EXPIRED"
    content.sound = UNNotificationSound(named:UNNotificationSoundName(rawValue: _currentTimer.getSoundEffect+".mp3"))

    let trigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger(timeInterval: TimeInterval(_currentTimer.endTime), repeats: false)
    let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: UUID().uuidString, content: content, trigger: trigger)

    center.add(request) { (error : Error?) in
        if let theError = error {
            print(theError.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It will crash if your interval is less than 60 seconds. That's by design. What is the timeInterval that you're using?

Comment: It's variable. The time interval is entered by the user and stored in _currentTimer.endTime. It's the time in seconds that the timer will run out.

Comment: I don't want a 20 minute timer just to restart, though. Not like this. I want a 20 minute timer to go off and keep going off until the user silences it.

Comment: All I was saying was, if it crashes because you've set `repeat` to `true` then it's likely because the timeInterval was less than 60 seconds. You still didn't answer as to what your `timerInterval` for when it crashed. Can you answer that?

Comment: Sure. In this case, it was less than 60 seconds. It was something like 5 seconds. The user can set a timer for any time he/she wants.

Comment: There is another restriction. That is the sound file can't be any longer than 30 seconds. Beyond that I _think_ the app will get terminated. Basically Apple doesn't want apps to annoy users :). So to my understanding you can't do what you want. But I'm 100% sure on that. Because I remember like 3-4 years ago using an app that required you to walk for its alarm to stop playing. And I don't it was shutting up after 30seconds. Maybe apple has added more restriction recently (past 2 years)

Answer (score 0):

So, the answer I'm going settling on with this question is that there is no answer. Apple does not want third party developers playing notification sounds for longer than 30 seconds in any circumstance, even if it is to build a timer app. Their timer in the Clock app will go off until you silence it, but third party developers aren't allowed to do that.